# Node cron job sending email every 2 seconds after caching

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, nodemailer, reddit

I'm trying to create a bot that sends me notifications every time an AskReddit post gets posted to Reddit. I have this app polling Reddit on Heroku every 2 seconds.

**The problem**

Every time there is a new post, an email gets sent to me. What should happen is that new post should get cached until a new post is put up on Reddit. What is happening instead is an email gets send every two seconds once a new post is posted; repeating the same email as before until a new post gets posted.

**What I have tried**

I have tried creating a cache variable called `latestCache` as you can see below to cache the last post. I have also tried slowing down the API calls to every 5 seconds. Both haven't worked though.

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

```
'use strict';

const snoostorm = require('snoostorm');
const snoowrap = require('snoowrap');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// NOTE: The following examples illustrate how to use snoowrap. However, hardcoding
// credentials directly into your source code is generally a bad idea in practice (especially
// if you're also making your source code public). Instead, it's better to either (a) use a separate
// config file that isn't committed into version control, or (b) use environment variables.

// Alternatively, just pass in a username and password for script-type apps.
const r = new snoowrap({
    userAgent: 'NodeJS',
    clientId: '******',
    clientSecret: '*****',
    username: '******',
    password: '******'
});

var latestCache;

var client = new snoostorm(new snoowrap(r));


var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://******@gmail.com:******@smtp.gmail.com');


var submissionStream = client.SubmissionStream({
    "subreddit": "AskReddit",
    "results": 1
});

submissionStream.on("submission", function(post) {
    if(post.title != latestCache.title){
        latestCache = post;

            var mailOptions = {
                from: '"Test message" <test@test.com>', // sender address
                to: '******@gmail.com', // list of receivers
                subject: 'Reddit post', // Subject line
                html: '' +
                '<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">' +
                '<tr><td colspan="2"><h1>New Reddit AskReddit post from ' + post.author.name + '</h1></td></tr>' +
                '<tr><td><strong>Post Link</strong></td><td> <a href="' + post.url + '">Post Link</a></td></tr>' +
                '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td> <a href="http://www.reddit.com/message/compose?to=' + post.author.name + '&subject=Response+to+loan+request">Reply to loan request</a></td></tr>' +
                '</table>'
            };

            // send mail with defined transport object
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
                if (error) {
                    return console.log(error);
                }
                console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would

1. Keep a cache of more than 1 past posts, possible upto 10-20. So that it can send in bulk every fixed minutes.
2. Push the new post into cache, and trigger a separate and throttled `sendMail` function

   ```
   const { throttle } = require('lodash')

   let posts = []

   submissionStream.on("submission", function(post) {
     posts.push({post})
     sendMail()
   })

   const sendMail = throttle(() => {
     // send mail here
     transporter.sendMail({
       subject: `${posts.length} new posts submitted`
     })
     // Either clear the cache
     posts = []
   }, 2000)
   ```
3. I'm not sure how `submissionStream` API works, but if you say that it's

   > repeating the same email

   then I'd just flag past posts as `sent` instead of clearing the cache entirely and filter out unsent posts and send those.

   ```
   const sendMail = throttle(() => {

     const postsToBeSent = posts.filter(p => !p.sent)

     transporter.sendMail({
       // ...
     })

     postsToBeSent.forEach(p => p.sent = true)

   }, 2000)
   ```